# rails create a caching table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I need to generate a new table in my db that pulls from various models to store data in a specific way. The models and relationships involved are:

```
Club  :has_many users
User :has_many posts, :has_many comments
```

Now I need the following columns (I hope the names are descriptive enough):

- Club Name
- Date
- NumUsersCreatedBeforeDate
- NumPostsByUsersBelongingToCurrentClubBeforeDate
- NumCommentsByUsersBelongingToCurrentClubBeforeDate

So there will be a new row for each club on each date, and the numbers in the 3 long named columns will be cumulative totals. This means that if I have 1000 clubs, and the app has been running for 30 days, I will have 30,000 rows, one for each club on each date.

I have a feeling all of this can't be done with one generate migration command, and I will have to generate a model specifically for this purpose. Any suggestions on building this table?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to cache this? All those columns could be done by sql queries. Unless you display it all over your app I'd do it on the fly. It'll be best to have a model for it and seemingly a daily cron job to create them.

Comment: it's for an admin page that shows overall stats (i'm already using active admin for my own admin page, this is supposed to be a separate and minimally functional admin page). I've gone the new model route, and I'm working out a rake task to update the table once a day.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it sorted then. My only suggestion would be to have it belong to a club rather than storing the club name. What if they change the name of the club?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to make a new model for this specific purpose, and create a rake task that iterates through each day the app has been running to populate the table with 1000 rows (one for each club) for each day, and then continues to update each day by populating another 1000 rows for the new day.